# Using an extended-ASCII collation table in C for Win32

Tags: c, sorting, winapi, collation, nls

In an existing app an API was used to convert all ASCII characters to an uppercased byte, for sorting purposes. cafe == CAFE == Café == CAFÉ. The characters e, é and E all became the character E, in a sorting name. So the value of table[137], representing the byte value of an é, was 69 ("E").

I've performed a few tests with an older, required Win32 API, which converted a whole string but didn't convert the character é to the character É nor to the expected character E.

How can this be done with an older Windows API?

Comment: There are many different 8 bit extended ASCII character sets, none of which make any sense to use these days. Use a Unicode encoding, and a Unicode library for collation.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take no as an answer. The app and the environments (not just Win32) are significantly older than "these days" (or perhaps even these decades), and aren't aware of Unicode, but presumably these days there is no such API for a current codepage anymore, Unicode is a bit over the top for an environment which isn't fully aware of Unicode, but I'll consider it for Win32. Nevertheless I was suprised that the é wasn't uppercased by one of the Win32 API's. (café -> CAFé). A table may be an option too, because the known number of known high-ASCII characters in use is 7.

Comment: If the standard C library function [toupper()](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/toupper) doesn't work for you, your best bet is probably just define your own, 256-byte lookup table.  Easy to do, fast at runtime ... and gives you complete control over a) character encoding (e.g. DOS codepage issues, like OEM 437 vs. OEM 858), and b) characters that don't easily map to English "A-Z" (like.  é, or \t).

Answer (score 1):

Solved, by finally almost doing what paulsm4 suggested.

The input codepage is, or should be, known: 850. 858 may be supported too, but let's assume 850. I already had to convert a few known characters to HTML, so I know which characters are occuring in the input text.

Instead of a table I'm using a function for the (14) exceptions (and a-z):

```
case 'ë':
case 'é':
   return 'E';
case 'ï':
   return 'I';
```

The original dynamic API (different operating system) or toupper() may be best indeed, albeit one may argue that é should become E or É.

With a limited and known number of exceptions a function, using static values, is an option too.

Finally one could use the other, original operating system to produce code for a static, full table with upto 256 elements. So you don't have to type 512 numbers manually and correctly.

The other, rare, old operating system has an API which returns <= 256 values, using the current codepage:

```
if (name[i]<=length_table)
   sortname[i]=table[i];
else
   sortname[i]=name[i];
```

New code:

```
sortname[i]=table(i);
```

Speed is not an issue, but the new function first takes care of more usual characters. It's customized, so I won't poost it here. In theory toupper() could be used if the character is <= 127 there.